React Native com expo não tem mais arquivos .js
Fala galera!
Recentemente criei um projeto em React Native com Expo e notei que os arquivos criados agora são diferentes. Não tem mais o arquivo App.js agora é outro arquivo em uma outra pasta com nome de index.tsx. Notei que toda a estrutura é bem diferente e não usa os componentes que eu usava antes.
Será que tem como voltar a criar os projetos a estrutura de antes?

Sim, existe como fazer isso. Apenas precisa trocar de .JSX para .JS.
Mas minha recomendação é para que você não faça isso, atualmente não importa muito a extensão do arquivo então como React não é javascript padrão, deixaria componentes React com .JSX e arquivos de script simples como .JS
Caso eu não tenha sido claro, você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui e em outros tópicos
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx
